# Trying to select programatically in JavaFX is not working

Tags: java, events, javafx, javafx-8

I am in the process of teaching myself JavaFX. Coming from the Swing world there are a lot of similarities between the 2. Especially event processing. Part of my process is to try and mimic an existing application as closely as possible. One of the things I am doing is creating a dialog that will allow the user to select a font to use. There is a text field for them to type in the font name and a list where they can scroll and select one. When they start typing the list will automatically scroll to through the list to start matching what the user is typing. I am also trying to populate the text field with the currently matched font name and then highlight the portion that the user has not typed yet so they can continue to type until the correct match is found.

For example if the user types the letter 't' on Windows the first font found is Tahoma. So the text field will be set to Tahoma and the carat will be positioned right after the 'T' and the 'ahoma' will be highlighted. What happens instead is that the field is populated with Tahoma and the carat is positioned at the end and nothing is highlighted. So it is like it is ignoring the 2 lines of code for positioning and highlighting or the event processor is causing my calls to JavaFX libraries to be run out of order.

I think this may be a bug with JavaFX but it could also be my misunderstanding of the event system. Please let me know which one and why.

Here is a complete sample code showing the problem. Just start typing in the text field to try it out.

```
package test;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestTyping extends Application {
    ChangeListener<String> textChange;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        TextField text = new TextField();
        root.setTop(text);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        textChange = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            text.textProperty().removeListener(textChange);
            for (String family : Font.getFamilies()) {
                if (family.equalsIgnoreCase(newValue) || family.toLowerCase().startsWith(newValue.toLowerCase())) {
                    text.setText(family);
                    text.positionCaret(newValue.length());
                    text.selectEnd();
                    break;
                }
            }
            text.textProperty().addListener(textChange);
        };
        text.textProperty().addListener(textChange);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap caret position and select end into `Platform.runLater`. The problem is in events order. I don't know correct details about this issue so I will not provide you a detailed answer, only solution.

```
Platform.runLater(()-> {
    text.positionCaret(newValue.length());
    text.selectEnd();
});
```

Comment: I will try that but my understanding is that I am already in the event thread so it should not be required.

Comment: I have tried your code with my fix and it is working. Caret is in typed position and text is highlighted to end.

Comment: Maybe it is my JRE version. I will try it later on a different computer. Thanks.

Comment: Was not my JRE version. I had the setText call inside the run later. Once I moved it out it worked. Thanks very much.

Comment: This doesn't play very nicely with deleting text (though that problem comes from the OP, not the solution).

Comment: I disagree. newValue will be a zero length string on delete. However I should short circuit the loop with a check for an empty string. Thanks.

Comment: @markbernard No: that's only true if you delete all the text. If you delete a portion of the text, `newText` will be the piece that remains. If you just hit backspace, it will delete the selected text, which of course is the additional text that was suggested. But then if you delete that, the same suggestion is made again, and you end up back where you started (so pressing backspace has no effect). For example, if I type "Ari", on my system it suggests "Arial", so by design "Arial" is displayed and "al" is selected. If I press backspace, "al" is deleted, so `newText="Ari"`, and `al` is added.

Comment: @James_D Ah yes. Thanks. I'll have to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative approach entirely, which uses a `TextFormatter` to modify changes to the text. The advantage here is that it doesn't rely on the "timing" of various property changes with respect to event handling, which is not documented and thus could possibly change in later JavaFX versions. It also avoids the slightly ugly "remove the listener and add it back" idiom.

```
import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter.Change;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestTyping extends Application {
    ChangeListener<String> textChange;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        TextField text = new TextField();
        root.setTop(text);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();


        UnaryOperator<Change> filter = c -> {

            // for delete, move the caret, or change selection, don't modify anything...
            if (c.getText().isEmpty()) {
                return c ;
            }


            for (String family : Font.getFamilies()) {
                if (family.toLowerCase().startsWith(c.getControlNewText().toLowerCase())) {
                    c.setText(family.substring(c.getRangeStart(), family.length()));
                    c.setAnchor(c.getControlNewText().length());
                    break ;
                }
            }

            return c ;

        };

        text.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<String>(filter));
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative. I will definitely consider it.